# How to get a minimum value for each entry in the string in sql IN statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the minimum value for each string element but I am always getting the minimum of all the values that I get after querying the sql.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT `assigned_to`,`appointment_lat`,`appointment_long`,`appointment_time` 
FROM `tb_schedules` 
WHERE `assigned_to` IN (26,27) 
AND ( appointment_time>'2014-09-23 07:33:00' ) 
GROUP BY `assigned_to` 
ORDER BY (DATEDIFF('2014-09-23 07:33:00',`appointment_time`)) 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what is a string element? please post the code that you are using, the actual result and the expected result.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with the expected result?

Comment: I am getting assigned_to and appointment_time as 26 & 2014-09-23 19:38:00 But there is another entry that is less than 2014-09-23 19:38:00.

Comment: you have multiple rows for a element and you want to select only these rows (for each element) for which app_time is minimum. right...?

Comment: yes but for every assigned_to that I passed in the string I want to get the min difference entry

Comment: can you do it if i provide you query which select only those data which have minimum appointment time. bcoz i am not understanding your full query.

Comment: well, let me help you getting the point. I am having a string of user_id that I am passing in the IN query and for every user_id I want to find the entry with the minimum difference between the assigned_to field and the date given. Now if with order by I use the LIMIT keyword then the query will return the minimum of all the data that I got with every user_id but I want to get the data (min difference) corresponding to every user_id individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the next appointment to a for each id listed:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT `assigned_to`,`appointment_lat`,`appointment_long`,`appointment_time` 
FROM `tb_schedules` 
WHERE `assigned_to` IN (26,27) 
AND appointment_time> now()
ORDER BY 4) x
GROUP BY `assigned_to`
```

This query makes use of mysql's non-standard group by capability, where if you don't specify all non-aggregate columns, it will pick one row for each unique grouped value(s) - according to the docs it's a random row, but in reality it is reliably the *first* row, so ordering before grouping gives you a predicable row.